# Jboss (Wildfly 9.0.1) - Remote EJB calls stops responding Intermittenly

Tags: jboss, ejb

We are upgrading JBOSS from (4.0.2) to latest Jboss (Wildfly 9.0.1) for our J2EE webApp. After upgrading we found that EJB calls are stop responding after 1 hour of load test.

Please note that the other areas of application is working fine where EJB is not used. The problem is only with remote EJB calls.

We have to restart Jboss to fix the issue.
Do we need to any configuration (threads/EJB pool) in Jboss (Wildfly 9.0.1)?

Comment: What you mean with "stop"? Connection timeout? Some error? Some warning?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to drop in and say that we're experiencing the same thing. What I recall reading is that this happens when the Wildfly has to wait to long to return an answer and suddenly the whole service becomes unresponsive.

We were running 8.2.0 Final and the only suggestion I could find was to upgrade. After performing an upgrade to 9.0.1 Final we're still seeing this. There was seemingly more people experiencing this but I have not been able to find any solution yet. The issues I found on the JBoss issue tracker on this have all been rejected and they're implying that it's more open for community discussion.

I have this lingering notion that toying around with timeouts might help though I haven't had time to try this yet.

P.S. I'm not privileged enough to simply comment which I would preferred.